# Return count of values in array not divisible evenly by 2

Tags: java, arrays, return

I've got an random array generated and I need a way to return the index of value of user input. So if it gives 8 random numbers, it then asks user to find a value in array.. Once that value is entered it needs to return the first index of that value. We haven't gone over this much in class and I don't know the best way to return this. Here's what I have so far:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter an integer to find in the array:");
int target = input.nextInt();

// Find the index of target in the generated array.

/*
** 3. write findValue **
*/
int index = findValue(array, target);


if (index == -1)
{
    // target was not found
    System.out.println("value " + target + " not found");
}
else
{
    // target was found
    System.out.println("value " + target + " found at index " + index);
}

}


/*
  allocate a random int[] array with size elements, fill with
  random values between 0 and 100
*/

public static int[] generateRandomArray(int size)
{
// this is the array we are going to fill up with random stuff
int[] rval = new int[size];

Random rand = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<rval.length; i++)
{
    rval[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
}

return rval;
}


/*
  print out the contents of array on one line,  separated by delim
*/
public static void printArray(int[] array, String delim)
{

// your code goes here
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(array));
}


/*
  return the count of values in array that are not divisible evenly by 2
*/
public static int countOdds(int[] array)
{
int count=0;

// your code goes here
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] %2 !=0) {
            count++;

        }
    }


return count;
}


/*
  return the first index of value in array.  Return -1 if value is not present.
*/
public static int findValue(int[] array, int value)
{
// your code goes here


return -1;

}


}
```

Comment: How would you find a name in a list of unsorted names on a paper ? It is exactly the same problem, and anybody can solve it naturally.

Comment: You title and description do not seem to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please fix your question title.

And now to the solution. How would you do that in real life? You would go through the array and check every single entry if it matches the searched value.
And thats exactly how you can do this in Java.

```
public static int findValue(int[] array, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // iterate over the content of the given array
        if (array[i] == value) { // check if the current entry matches the searched value
            return i; // if it does return the index of the entry
        }
    }
    return -1; // value not found, return -1
}
```

Here is an example for calling this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    System.out.println(findValue(array, 6));
}
```

This will print `5`, because the number 6 is on the 5th position in the given array. Keep in mind that the index starts with `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've only been in this class for 2 weeks and just started doing java programming so I'm trying to get a grasp on a lot of these things.